# JavaFX Scene Builder 2.0 "Failed to include '*.fxml' "

Tags: javafx, include, scenebuilder, failed-installation

In Scene Builder, I included many fxml files in Tabs, but now, I can not include any. Also, if I delete my existing fxml file which doesn't have any problem, and then add again by using Scene Builder's  include function(File->Include->FXML..), I get the same error:

"Failed to include '*.fxml' under Tab."

**EDIT:**  I get same error in gluon scene builder 8.3.0.

Comment: What error is it giving you or it is just refusing to open the fxml file?

Comment: That version of Scene Builder is no longer supported. You should consider upgrading to http://gluonhq.com/labs/scene-builder/

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Scene builder says only "Failed to include 'blabla.fxml'". Also, I get same error in gluon scene builder 8.3.0. However, I discovered an interesting error. If I don't add fxml file as include under "Tab", scene builder is not giving error. I think that problem is being because of "Tab", but I don't have any solution.

Comment: I think that problem related to java side. Scene builder works fine. This problem solved when I established the java root connections properly.

Answer (score 0):

I experience the same issue with SceneBuilder 8.3.0, Eclipse Neon + Oracle JDK8 on Linux.

However, using a phrase as such

```
<Tab fx:id="tab1" text="Untitled Tab 1">
  <content>
    <fx:include id="tab1" source="Tab1View.fxml"/>
  </content>
</Tab>
```

directly in the FXML file, it works as expected. 
PS: I am wondering whether this is a bug or an unwanted feature.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know your solution but my problem is not realted to your answer. I didn't do anything but problem is solved. I don't know. My computer is interesting, maybe :). I hope, your solution helps to the people.

Comment: This causes weird issuse with SceneBuilder, usually resulting in a crash. So I would recommend instancing it in controller's initialize() using FXMLLoader.